# Inconsistencies in installing 3rd party libraries in Angular 2

Tags: angular, firebase

I'm working my way through Angular 2 and have run into a few issues with 3rd party libraries

1. Some libraries such as Firebase [suggest using Webpack](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2)
2. Other libraries such as [Material 2 only have instructions](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) for installing using the Broccoli installer which generates the angular-build-cli file that Webpack doesn't create

How do I best go about including both libraries in my project? Should I simply stick with the Broccoli installer or are there any work arounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI the angular-cli build tool is moving away from broccoli and has a test branch for webpack.

You can install it using `npm install angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.2`

From there, you just need to install the material packages and typings. I believe that webpack is smart enough to know it needs to include files from the `import` statements.
I've got moment.js and lodash added into my webpack project and it was a simple as installing them and their typings.

That being said, last I checked material was NOT working with RC6 as a result of the recent changes to how modules are imported into your application.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I installed webpack as you suggested. What would be the best way to install material design now?

Comment: You should be able to follow the exact same instructions listed here
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md
You can just skip the parts where they talk about the angular-cli-build.js file and system-config.ts file. Webpack will grab and load up all relevant packages based on your imports.